# How to implement pressing a key to jump between beginning and end of current line in VsVim

Tags: visual-studio, vsvim

I want to write a vim move: pressing `s` key to jump between beginning and end of current line. I achieved this in neovim and ideavim, but I don't know how to do this in VsVim(Vim mode plugin for Visual Studio).

For neovim (or vscode neovim plugin), I can write following vimscript to implement pressing `s` key to jump between beginning and end of current line:

```
noremap <expr>s col(".")==1?"$":"0"
```

For ideaVim, I can write this to achieve same effect:

```
noremap <expr> s col('.') == 1 ? '$' : '0'
```

But I can't do this in VsVim .vimrc file. It seems VsVim do not support column function like `col()`. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Thanks for any help.